# SQL Query with Average and Grouping

Tags: sql-server

I just want to ask you guys, especially those with MsSQL knowledge, regarding my query.

My goal is to get the average delivery time and group my data by delivery date and  route id daily/weekly/monthly.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
RouteID,
CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) AS delivery_date,
AVG(
    DATEDIFF(
        day, 
        CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]),
        CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate])
        )
    ) as Averate_Delivery_Time
  FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
  WHERE 
    [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND 
    [UnloadDate] != 0 AND
    [StageID] = 'D' AND 
   ( CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) LIKE '%2016%' or
    CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) LIKE '%2017%')
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]), [RouteID]
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) DESC
```

I am not confident if the average delivery time is correct so if you think it's wrong or there are other things in my query that needs to be corrected, please let me know.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get the right query:

```
SELECT [RouteID], 
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + 
CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name,
AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, 
[DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days 
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > 
[UnloadDate] 
AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]), 
[RouteID] 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]), 
Average_Delivery_Days desc
```

But I have a more complicated query to do now. I have this sample data:

```
RouteID  |  week_name  |  yearnum  |  weeknum  |  Average_Delivery_Days
=======================================================================
MK       | 2016 Week 2 | 2016      |  2        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TSM      | 2016 Week 2 | 2016      |  2        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
E        | 2016 Week 2 | 2016      |  2        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
A        | 2016 Week 2 | 2016      |  2        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
D        | 2016 Week 2 | 2016      |  2        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
MP       | 2016 Week 2 | 2016      |  2        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CTN      | 2016 Week 3 | 2016      |  3        | 9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
BIS      | 2016 Week 3 | 2016      |  3        | 8
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C        | 2016 Week 3 | 2016      |  3        | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
PN       | 2016 Week 4 | 2016      |  4        |10
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make the above data be like:

- MK and TSM are merged into 1 new routeID like Manila1
- E, A, and D are merged into another as Manila2
- MP, CTN, AND BIS as Visayas
- C and PN as Mindanao
- and so on..

And the average delivery days will be changed as well.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Have you calculated some of the values manually to see if they agree with what the query is returning? As asked above, sample data and desired result would help a lot.